# R ggplot2: How to make a histogram and color according to diferent columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, data-visualization

I am trying to generate a [histogram](/questions/tagged/histogram) with some data, but I can't find a way to make [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) work to achieve what I want.

For context, my data looks like this: (column names)

```
&#x200B;

|  Name  |  Total Enrichment % (A+B+C+D)  |  %A  |  %B  |  %C  |  %D  |
```

I want to generate a histogram showing the distribution of the total Enrichment column and then filling the column with 4 colors showing the different percentages of A, B, C, and D.

I've tried to convert the data into long format, but still, I cannot seem to get exactly what I want.

Any advice would be very helpful! Thank you very much!

Here is an example (it's not the original data, just a small part of it):

```
    dat <- read.table(text = "Name Total A B C D
1 0.1396104 0.029220779 0.009740260 0.029220779 0.07142857
2 0.1250000 0.010869565 0.021739130 0.016304348 0.07608696
3 0.1337580 0.006369427 0.000000000 0.025477707 0.10191083
4 0.1239669 0.016528926 0.024793388 0.033057851 0.04958678
5 0.1242938 0.011299435 0.016949153 0.039548023 0.05649718
6 0.1311475 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.021857923 0.10928962
7 0.1376147 0.004587156 0.004587156 0.004587156 0.12385321
8 0.1574074 0.046296296 0.018518519 0.032407407 0.06018519
9 0.1269036 0.010152284 0.010152284 0.020304569 0.08629442", sep = "",    header=T)
```

My goal is to create a histogram with the Total enrichment data, but with each column filled with the other contribution variables (A, B, C and D)

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks to StupidWolf amazing help and comments I could come a little bit closer to what I want.

Here is what I've fot so far (It's not perfect, but so far so good)

[image]

What I would like to do is to have the y axis in logarithmic scale, since I have a lot of data in the lower range, and I'm also interesed in the data with a higher enrichment.
Also, does anyone know why the bars are not filled? Why are there these white spaces?

Again, thank you very much for your help and patience!

Comment: Look up stacked barplots.

Comment: Provide the data in `dput()` format.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what  hasn't worked.

Comment: Per @camille comment, need more details to understand exactly what you're looking to do, but example 4 seems like what you're trying to do: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making an educated guess on what you want to do, first let's get some data:

```
set.seed(321)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dat = data.frame(Name=1:500,matrix(runif(500*4),ncol=4))
colnames(dat)[-1] = LETTERS[1:4]
dat$Total = rowSums(dat[,-1])
```

If you want to calculate the contribution of A,B,C and D to each binned value of Total, then we need to do a histogram of Total, it looks like this, and we store the breaks to classify each row:

```
his_all = hist(dat$Total,br=40)
dat$bin = cut(dat$Total,br=his_all$breaks,labels=his_all$mids)
```

[image]

In the above, I used the middle of the histogram to represent the position to plot the bar again. Hence there's a step to convert the factor label to numeric. Then we need to calculate the contribution of A to D to each total, then pivot longer and plot :

```
dat %>% 
mutate_at(c("A","B","C","D"),~.x/Total) %>% 
pivot_longer(A:D) %>% 
mutate(bin=as.numeric(as.character(bin))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=bin,y=value,fill=name)) + 
geom_col() +
xlab("enrichment")
```

[image]

Another way to visualize your data:

```
dat$interval = cut_interval(dat$Total,5)

dat %>% mutate_at(c("A","B","C","D"),~.x/Total) %>% 
group_by(interval) %>% select(c(interval,A:D)) %>% 
summarize_all(mean) %>% pivot_longer(-interval) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=interval,y=value,fill=name)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

This shows you for every range of Total, what proportion of A/B/C/D contributes to it..

Comment: This is very useful! 
However I've encountered a few problems when using it with my data... First, I cannot manage to find a way to make a histogram like the last one but with logarithmic scales and following the same steps as the ones you showed... Is there any way to make the y axis in log scale without screwing all the histogram? I've tried scale_y_log() but the result makes no sense...

Comment: Well, it didn't do much... (see the post) :)

Comment: Ok i see now. sorry I read too quickly, I though you need something on the x-axis. Your plot will not make sense with a log y axis... Because if you go up one log scale, the increment is multiplicative, which makes the stacking super confusing. Rather than come up with some plot, I have to tell you this is going to be wrong..

Comment: I see... It makes sense! Is there any way that I can plot it? Maybe another way to visualize it? Because the only thing that comes to my mind is splitting the data and plot the high enriched and low enriched separately... But that's not ideal...

Comment: Break your values into quantiles / sextiles  and show the proportion? So if there is an effect, you will see an enrichment towards one side of the plot. I.e you show two plots, one being the overall histogram, 2nd one showing the distribution

Comment: I am very sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what do you mean...
I separate the data into quantiles and... what distribution do I show? Sorry, I'm confused...

Comment: Ok from what I see, your distribution is very skewed to lower total enrichment. I edit my answer above to show this. Hopefully it helps but otherwise you might need to think more about visualization?

Comment: It's amazing! I like it a lot how the data looks! Thank you very much!!